# iterate through a JSON field in django

Tags: python, django, json, django-socialauth

With `django-social-auth`, it allows you to capture certain details and as a result a Dropbox users `extra_data` looks as follows

```
{"access_token": "oauth_token_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_token=YYYYYYYYYYY", "7200": null, "id": null}
```

The models.py is set up as follows.

```
class UserSocialAuth(models.Model):
    """Social Auth association model"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='social_auth')
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    extra_data = JSONField(blank=True)
```

How do I access oauth_token and oauth_token_secret separately?

Answer (score 1):

Parse the JSON data with `simplejson` module:

```
from django.utils.simplejson import loads

data = {"access_token": "oauth_token_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXX&oauth_token=YYYYYYYYYYY", "7200": null, "id": null} tokens = parse_qs(loads(data)['access_token'])

json_dict = loads(data)
access_token = json_dict['access_token']
```

Then use what Jan suggested to you to parse the query string stored in `access_token`:

```
from urlparse import parse_qs

tokens = parse_qs(access_token)

print tokens['oauth_token_secret']
print tokens['oauth_token']
```

Answer (score 0):

For parsing the `access_token`, you can use http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs:

> Parse a query string given as a string argument (data of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Data are returned as a dictionary. The dictionary keys are the unique query variable names and the values are lists of values for each name.